# Convert php query string to seo url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currenlty I am getting all data from MySQL database using following PHP query string:

```
ccroipr.php?id=201801161516084475
```

from this link:

```
<a href="ccroipr.php?id=201801161516084475">Profile</a>
```

Now

I want the URL should be ccroipr-201801161516084475

From this link

```
<a href="ccroipr-201801161516084475">Profile</a>
```

currenlty, Using following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/$ ccroipr.php?id=$1
```

It's accepting this URL:

```
ccroipr?201801161516084475
```

Not this one:

```
ccroipr-201801161516084475
```

How can I do this using .htaccess?

**Update:**

**Ajax/jQuery Code**

```
$('#register').submit(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();        
    var formData = $('form').get(0);    
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST', 
        dataType : 'html',
        data: new FormData(formData),
        url : 'process/ccroipr-cat-p.php', 
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend : function () {
            $('#result').html( 'Please wait...' );
            $('#registerButton').prop('disabled', true);
        },
        success : function ( result ) {            
            $('#registerButton').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#result').html( result );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: _“It's accepting this URL: `ccroipr?201801161516084475`”_ - that likely has nothing to do with your rewrite attempt at all, but is just the result of MultiViews finding the PHP file of the same name, `ccroipr.php`. _“Not this one: `ccroipr-201801161516084475`”_ - and considering that your pattern requires a _slash_ at the front, in the middle and at the end, this now surprises you how exactly …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule using `-` as delimiter:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?[^-]*-(.+?)/?$ ccroipr.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Object not found if I go to this url: `ccroipr-201801161516084475`

Comment: Hi, something happening. If I place the .htaccess file in our site root directory then jQuery/Ajax call is not working but If I remove it then it's working fine. Do you know why?

Comment: Needed to skip real files and directories from this rule.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this, worked for me.

```
RewriteRule ^site/([a-zA-Z])$ ccroipr.php?id=$1
```